# Is $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Our teacher told us that:

$$\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \cong \mathbb{C}$$

the proof should be the following homomorphism:

$$\phi: (\mathbb{R}[x],+,*) \to (\mathbb{C},+,*)$$
$$\phi(f) = f(i)$$

But shouldn't the homomorphism be surjective? It certainly isn't: $\pi \in \mathbb{C}$, but there is no $f, f \in \mathbb{R}[x], f(i) = \pi$. Am I right? How can I fix this?

Comment: Of course there is: $\;f(x):=\pi\;$ , or if you prefer: $\;f(x):=x^2+\pi+1\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly surjective, as any constant is a polynomial.

Comment: Sometimes it amazes me how stupid I can get after midnight.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton Ah ah, don't worry! Everyone misses the obvious once in a while!  :)

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed: the constant polynomial $\pi$.

Actually, defining a homomorphism of $\mathbf R[x]$  to another (commutative) $\mathbf R$-algebra amounts to defining the image $\alpha$ of the indeterminate $x$. Then, for any polynomial $p$, this homomorphism maps $p$ onto $p(\alpha)$.

Then you can check $\ker\phi$ is the ideal of  $\mathbf R[x]$ generated by $x^2+1$, whence the isomorphism mentioned by your professor.